# Execution of an extracted *.exe resource is failing while launching the standalone Jar

Tags: java, maven

I'm Trying to execute an *.exe file after extracting it from the project resources to a local/temporary path. It is working fine when I run the code through NetBeans. The problem comes when I build it for an Standalone Jar. Simply doesn't run, is not extracting the resource and not executing it.

I omitted the instantiation for brevity.

```
public class MyClass {

    public MyClass() {

    }

    public void extractExe() {
        try {
            // Get resource as stream
            InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resource.exe");

            // Set the output path for the stream
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:/path/to/resource.exe");

            // Copy the resource to the path
            IOUtils.copy(in, out);

            // Close the streams
            in.close();
            out.close();

            // Execute it !
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:/path/to/resource.exe");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex); 
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how my pom.xml looks like, it just load the dependencies, and builds a jar with the libraries included within it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.jeflopo</groupId>
    <artifactId>Myclass</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-standalone</finalName>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.jeflopo.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

It works fine and no errors given When I execute it in Netbeans or through the commandline with:

```
java -cp myjar.jar com.jeflopo.Main
```

But It doesn't work when I doubleclick the .jar

I'm not an expert, could anyone help me to debug the error ?

Comment: post your `jar` manifest file.

Comment: I Would like to, but I think that I haven't such file in my project :$ I have the pom.xml, nbactions.xml files, /src and the /target folders. I have executed ``mvn package`` in the folder of the project. But it is not creating a meta-inf/manifest.mf for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what I have done to make it work again. But It's working now.

I have executed it by command line, I have run the command "mvn package" and still It wasn't working launching by double click.

I just went to eat, and when I have returned I have tried again... And now it launch.

Ehm... @Sajan Chandran suggested to show the manifest file, but I think that since i'm not using **maven-jar-plugin** I haven't a manifest file. I'm just using **maven-assembly-plugin** to assemble all the dependencies in just one distributable archive.

Thanks anyway.
And excuse my grammar, english isn't my first lang...